# Unhandled exception at 0x0040224d in new_srdProg_d.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd1

Tags: c++

I am getting the Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1 error. I´m using a vc9 compiler.

My code:

```
#define SRD_EXPORTS
#include "SRD.h"
#include "ISRDPresenter.h"
#include "ISRDFactory.h"
#include "ISRDevice.h"

#include "AString.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    ISRDPresenter* dev = (ISRDPresenter*)malloc(sizeof(ISRDPresenter));     // = NewSRDPresenter();

    char act[ 128 ];
    int commands = argc-1;

do
{
    if( !commands )
    {
        act[ 0 ] = 0;
        printf("SRD> ");
#if defined(__IBMC__) || defined (__IBMCPP__)
        fflush(stdout);
#endif
        fgets( act, 128, stdin );
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy( act, argv[ argc - commands-- ], 128 );
        printf("SRD> %s\n", act);
    }

    if( !strncmp( act, "help", 4 ) )
    {
        dev->showHelp( act );
    }
...
}
```

The error is in the line dev->showHelp(act);
The problem should be in the line

```
ISRDPresenter* dev = (ISRDPresenter*)malloc(sizeof(ISRDPresenter));
```

But I can´t fix it. 
If I use instead:

```
ISRDPresenter* dev = NewSRDPresenter();
```

It says identifier cannot be found, and if I use:

```
ISRDPresenter* dev = new ISRDPresenter();
```

says that ISRDPresenter cannot instantiate abstract class...

ISRDPresenter.h:

```
#ifndef __ISRDPRESENTER_H
#define __ISRDPRESENTER_H

#define SRD_EXPORTS
#include "SRD.h"
#include "ISRDDataTypes.h"

#include "AIPClass.h"
class ISRDFactory;

class ISRDPresenter
{    
public:
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Destructor
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
virtual ~ISRDPresenter() {};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Function prototypes
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------  
virtual void showHelp( char* attr ) const = 0;
virtual void showList( void ) const = 0;
virtual void showInfo( size_t i ) const = 0;
virtual void showFirmware( size_t i ) const = 0; 
};

#endif /* __ISRDPRESENTER_H */
```

SRDPresenter.h:

```
#ifndef __SRDPRESENTER_H
#define __SRDPRESENTER_H

#define SRD_EXPORTS
#include "SRD.h"
#include "ISRDPresenter.h"

#include "AString.h"
#include "ISRDFactory.h"

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ASRDPresenter
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ASRDPresenter : public ISRDPresenter
{
public:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ASRDPresenter constructor & destructor
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ASRDPresenter();
virtual ~ASRDPresenter(){};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function prototypes
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void showHelp( char* attr  ) const;
void showList( void ) const;
void showInfo( size_t i ) const;
void showFirmware( size_t i ) const;

private:
    ISRDFactory* f_srds;

};

SRD_EXPORT_PREF ISRDPresenter* SRD_EXPORT_POST NewSRDPresenter()
{
    return new ASRDPresenter();
}


#endif /* __SRDPRESENTER_H */
```

SRDPresenter.cpp:

```
#define SRD_EXPORTS
#include "SRDPresenter.h"

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  ASRDPresenter
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ASRDPresenter::ASRDPresenter()
:f_srds( )
{
    // empty
}

void ASRDPresenter::showHelp( char* attr ) const
{

    if( !strcmp( attr, "help" ) )
    {
        printf( "\nHelp to the ANOVIS SRD command.\n\n" );
        printf( " help                : Print this help.\n" );
        printf( " list                : List all ANOVIS SRD found.\n" );
        printf( " info        
    }    
...
}
```

How can I fix it? Light!
Thanx in advance!

Comment: why malloc within c++?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate ISRDPresenter, it is an abstract class!

Comment: Don't spam tags. C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: C is included in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `malloc` instead of `new`, you've skipped the initialization of the object. The pattern `cdcdcdcd` is written to freshly allocated memory in debug mode builds to help you detect this kind of problem. You're trying to access a virtual function, which is accessing a vtable which hasn't been initialized.

You *should* be able to do:

```
ISRDPresenter* dev = new ASRDPresenter;
```

Comment: Thanxs it was a header problem, it works now with:

    ISRDPresenter* dev = new ASRDPresenter;